# How to efficiently encode a Scala tuple in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Given the following type

```
type GeoLocation = (Double, Double)
```

I would like to store this in my database as

```
location: [-55.23, 123.7]
```

Furthermore, the location data is optional, so the API exposes `Option[GeoLocation]`. When it's time to store the data, I convert it.

```
val coordinates: Option[GeoLocation] = ...
val location = coordinates match {
  case Some((lng, lat)) => Some(lng :: lat :: Nil)
  case None => None
}
```

So that I can optionally add it to the containing document.

```
location.map(doc.put("location", _))
```

And when I want to convert if from a database object back to a `GeoLocation`, I do this nasty bit...

```
val coordinates = dbo.getAs[MongoDBList]("location").map(_.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double])) match {
  case Some(List(lng, lat)) => Some(lng, lat)
  case None => None
}
```

It seems to me that there is a lot of ceremony in storing a tuple in MongoDB as an array. Is there a more efficient and direct way to accomplish this?

Comment: ever get a better answer this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler way to write the same thing:

```
val coordinates = dbo.getAs[Seq[Double]]("location").map { case Seq(lng, lat) => (lng, lat) }
```

If you want to be more protective (not getting MatchError if you have more than two elements in the array) you can "catch" the rest:

```
val coordinates = dbo.getAs[Seq[Double]]("location") match {
    case Some(Seq(lng, lat)) => Some(lng, lat)
    case _ => None
  }
```